# meaning of 'rise to do'

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What does 'rise to (do)' mean in this sentence? Something like 'come to' or 'get to'?

They later went to work at regular jobs. But none rose to become a good scholar or a fine artist.

Comment: "Rise up in the ranks" -- attain higher rank or skill level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's closer to "get to" (or, more closely, "go on to"/"went on to") than "come to", unless the speaker and audience are all fine scholars and artists.